# Sulfur iodide to produce alkyl iodides

Tags: organic-chemistry

Phosphorus halides react with alcohols to give alkyl halides. I think that a similar reaction would be possible with sulfur halides. In particular, sulfur iodides. While these are not stable at room temperature, they could hypothetically exist as intermediates, and quickly react with the alcohol solvent they are in. Simply combining sulfur and iodine in an alcoholic solution, with stirring and a hot water bath might be able to form this intermediate. Do you believe that such a method would work? I attached a reaction mechanism below.[image: The hypothetical reaction mechanism for the reaction of sulfur diiodide with ethanol]

Comment: I think you should better ask why SI2 isn't stable.

Comment: Carbocations aren't stable, but those are often intermediates in reactions. A lot of intermediates cannot be isolated, but are still formed in the reaction. Just because SI2 isn't stable as a pure compound does not mean that it is not a viable intermediate.

Comment: The fault of your logic is while $\ce{P}$ in $\ce{PX3}$ is a Lewis acid while $\ce{S}$ in $\ce{SX2}$ (e.g., $\ce{SCl2}$) is a Lewis base.